# For loop output

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

A couple of days back i posted here ([Sum of previous two numbers entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956242/sum-of-previous-two-numbers-entered)) about the sum of two numbers, now  i have got to the last part and require more help.

I want to show the output of the last number centered around minus. the total number of characters should be 20. So if the last number is 16 there should be 2 minus either side. and if its an odd number there should be an odd number of minuses to the right.

this is what i have

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Interact {

```
public static void menu (){

        System.out.print(" Select one of the option below\n" +
                 "  1 -     Enter a new number\n " +
                 "  2 - Show the sum of the last two number\n" +
                 "  3 - Show the current number as pluses\n" +
                 "  4 - Show the current number as centred pluses\n" );

        }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int no=0;  
    int option;

    int last = 0;
    int beforeLast = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


     do {
         menu();
         option=input.nextInt();

     switch (option) {

         case 1:

            System.out.print("Please enter a number between 0 and 20 : "  ); 
            no=input.nextInt();

            beforeLast = last;
            last = no;

            break;


         case  2:
            System.out.println("The Sum of the Numbers is : " + (last+beforeLast));
            break;

        case 3:

            int i;
            int j =0;
                               for (i=0; i<last; i++) {
                   System.out.print("+");
                   }
            for (j=20;j>last;j--){
                       System.out.print("-");}
            break;


        case 4: 
            int div=2;
            for (j=20;j>last;j--){
                       System.out.print("-");}
               for (i=0; i<last; i++) {
                   System.out.print("+");
                   }
            for (j=20;j>last;j--){
                       System.out.print("-");}
            break;          
         default :
             System.out.print("Invalid option");


     } 
 } while (option !=5);
}
```

}

If the number is 12 there should be 4 minuses on the left and right but my output shows 8 on both sides

--------++++++++++++--------

If the number is odd, the extra minus should be printed on the right

Comment: Your code is a mess. Please read Java doc to learn how to format code.

Comment: Okay, and what is your question? What's wrong with your current code? What issues have you encountered trying to implement what you've described? All you've posted is a description of a program and some code. We can't be sure what you need help with unless you add more details.

Comment: I don't wanna mention it again but you really need to do some things with your code. First - you should use Ctrl+Shift+F(Eclipse) to autofromat your code. Second - get rid of this programming style: some variables here some numbers there and run...why my program doens't work? For example you create new int div in case 4 but you don't use it. It's bery bad programming practice. And use final ints for cases. Something like this: case ENTER_THE_NUMBER_OPTION. It looks much better than just case 1.

Comment: okay i will work on all of this, thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prettygeek is right, your code is a mess... Anyway try this...

```
int side = (20 - last) / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < side; i++) {
    System.out.print("-");
}
for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
    System.out.print("+");
}
for (int i = 0; i < side; i++) {
    System.out.print("-");
}
```

Comment: You mean Preetygeek, not ProfessorChaos.

Comment: Yes, the mess of the code distracted me...

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works, I will work on the format.          Edit - I created another attribute, and a for loop for the minus sight if the input number is odd.